# mysql finding unmatched record if 2 columns not matched

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to find out unmatched records from 2 tables i had tried below query it works fine but i need to find for multiple column matching plz help

```
res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp.roll_no NOT IN (SELECT emp_no FROM emp_old)");
```

similarly i had did as follows..
it has error..

`emp` has `rollno` and `name`

`emp_old` has `emp_no` and `name`

i need to find out for this two columns which are unmatched

```
res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE emp.roll_no AND emp.name NOT IN (SELECT emp_no AND name FROM emp_old)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  emp e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    1 
  FROM
    emp_old 
  WHERE emp_no = e.emp.roll_no)
```

or simply

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  emp  
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    1 
  FROM
    emp_old 
  )
```

**EDIT** i have added another column of color in query which will give you color  red  if not matched and green for matched employee

```
SELECT *
,(CASE WHEN eo.emp_no IS NULL THEN 'red' ELSE 'green') color
 FROM emp e
LEFT JOIN emp_old eo ON (e.roll_no = eo.emp_no)
```

**Highlight**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
echo "<tr>"; echo "<td align='center' width='200'><span style='background-color:red;'>" . $row['emp_no'] . "</span></td>";
echo "<td align='left' width='200'><span style='background-color:red;'>" . $row['name'] . "</span></td>"; echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Comment: yeah thanks its working now SELECT * FROM emp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM emp_old WHERE emp_no = emp_old.emp_no AND name = emp_old.name)"); but i need to separate which emp_no and name unmatched list.. is it possible separation may be with color..

Comment: @arun i didn't got your point the above query will give you the employees which are no in `emp_old` so you have the unmatched results if you also want to get matched then use same query but with `EXISTS` only

Comment: SELECT * FROM emp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM emp_old WHERE emp_no = emp_old.emp_no AND name = emp_old.name)"); i had tried this its working its listing out unmatched list of 2 columns emp_no & name i want to highlight this two columns according to result

Comment: If you need to highlight the results you need to fetch the results first and then use some css to highlight

Comment: i think if we use css it will highlight whole column i want for particular result..               while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td align='center' width='200'>" . $row['emp_no'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='left' width='200'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this using JOIN, instead of subquery

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM   emp e 
LEFT JOIN emp_old eo 
ON e.rollno = eo.emp_no AND e.name = eo.name
WHERE eo.emp_no IS NULL AND eo.name IS NULL;
```

Please have a look at [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/038c2/1)